# Form input in a foreach loop returns empty model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a list object for which I tried to display text boxes in a foreach loop. However the post returns empty object. I couldn't see the cause.

Here is the code in the view

<%using (Html.BeginForm("makeTransfer", "shareTransfer")) { %>

```
        <% foreach (var i in Model.Inform)//int i = 0; i < Model.Inform.Count(); i++){ %>
                <%:Html.HiddenFor(x=>i.shares, new{@value = i.shares}) %> 
              ...
                <td style = "width:20px"><%:Html.TextBoxFor(x=>i.sharesRq)%></td> cuddling
        <%} %>

    <%:Html.HiddenFor(x => x.accSrc, new { @value = Model.accSrc })%>
            <%:Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.accDst, new{ @value = Model.accDst}) %>

    Date of Transfer<%:Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.date)%>
            Transfer with benefit<%:Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.withBenefit)%>

       <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" /></div>
       <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel" /></div>
```

<%} %>

And Here is the controller

public ActionResult makeTransfer(vmTransfer transfer, string save, string cancel)
        {

```
        if (cancel != null)
            return RedirectToAction("startTransfer");

        else if (save != null)
        {

            foreach (var t in transfer.Inform)
            { ...
```

My problem is, transfer.Inform( 2nd line from the last) which is a list is empty when the form posts. Any help please, ASAP.

Comment: Please, can you edit the code part.

Comment: Please consider the line just above the gray box, as part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you using editor templates instead of writing any loops in your views:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("makeTransfer", "shareTransfer")) { %>
    <%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.Inform) %>
    <%= Html.HiddenFor(x => x.accSrc, new { @value = Model.accSrc }) %>
    <%= Html.HiddenFor(x => x.accDst, new { @value = Model.accDst }) %>
    Date of Transfer <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.date) %>
    Transfer with benefit <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.withBenefit) %>

    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" /></div>
    <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel" /></div>  
<% } %>
```

and in the corresponding editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/InformViewModel.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<AppName.Models.InformViewModel>" 
%>
<%= Html.HiddenFor(x => x.shares) %> 
...
<td style="width:20px">
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.sharesRq) %>
</td>
```

Remark: you might need to adjust the name of the editor template based on the type of the `Inform` property.

Editor templates will take care of generating proper id and names of the input fields so that everything binds correctly:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult makeTransfer(vmTransfer transfer, string save, string cancel)
{
    if (cancel != null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("startTransfer");
    }
    else if (save != null)
    {
        foreach (var t in transfer.Inform)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Darin, I used this on the user control: